# How to get value of meta_key and post it on any page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this in database:

[image]

I want to post the meta_value. How to do that? I want for each post_id to post the assigned meta_value on the same page, and that automatically.

How I can retrieve the meta_value and post it?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your single.php or custom-post-type-single.php

```
<?php $key_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'property_bathrooms' ); ?>
```